# Firefox problems with Opacity on SVG "Use" elements that have Masks

Tags: firefox, svg, mask, xlink

I recently noticed one of my SVG images seemed to lose its translucence when viewed in Firefox. I've been tracking down the problem and its led me to `opacity` not being obeyed when a `use` element (specifically) has a `mask` attached.

I was able to use `fill-opacity` to work-around the issue, but that's not ideal. I'm not entirely sure whats causing it and if its a bug that should be reported to `firefox`, or if I'm just making a mistake somewhere.

I've put this JSFiddle together to illustrate the issue and alternatives:
https://jsfiddle.net/bg4o5y63/

In Chrome, Edge and IE11 all the examples appear the same (as expected), but in Firefox 64.0.2 (latest) **#1** doesn't obey the specified `opacity`.

This also seems to affect `use` elements that are utilized inside `masks` that themselves has a `mask`.

Any thoughts as to what might be causing this, or if I'm slipping up somewhere?

**Edit (Screenshot attached):**
[image]

Comment: Not sure what I'm supposed to see here. It looks the same in Safari and Firefox on my Mac.

Comment: For Firefox on Windows the first example does not obey the opacity. What version of FF on the Mac are you using?

Comment: both the official 64.0.2 and one built from the latest source with random unrelated things I'm currently working on. Presumably it's a Windows thing then. You should raise a bug in [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/)

Comment: Thx will try on Mac and Linux and raise with Mozilla.